# Form submission with Ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file that has an HTML form that submits via AJAX to the database. When I hit the form submit button, every PHP query updates itself. Is this how Ajax normally operates? or if I switch the parent file from PHP to HTML, will it eliminate the unwanted updating of all the PHP on the page?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax submits the request to a seperate php file to load data. You can choose to load only poritions of pages. `$.load` does this easier. Look here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You said it submits via AJAX to the database - but have you actually programmed it to do that?

Post a sample of the AJAX code and we can check it for you.

I have a feeling you don't really understand the technology you are using. What is a 'PHP query'? You want to switch the page from PHP to HTML? Well, can you? Does the page have PHP in it or not? It wouldn't make any difference to AJAX code, but I have a feeling you don't actually have AJAX code.

Comment: That is a bit harsh seeing that I have everything working perfectly until there is a conflict with a ranking system. I have content being sorted via Query where it picks an entry ORDER BY points. When I submit the vote via ajax, and this vote pushes it ahead of the next, the buttons become useless because it is working for the content that got replaced. This is happening because my query SELECT id from table ORDER BY rank DESC is updating after every ajax submit . I need that ID to stay static until and actual page refresh.

Comment: Of course it's harsh - what you wrote in this comment sounds nothing like what you wrote in your question. Do you think we can read your mind? You need to write a complete question that is actually possible to answer. You have given zero useful information, I gave the best answer I could for the information you gave. Even the info you added in this comment isn't enough - how are we supposed to help you when we know nothing whatsoever about how you are getting the SELECT id? We know nothing about how you are doing the ajax. I think you should start over, this time with a *complete* question.

Comment: BTW, when you do post a new question, and/or update this one, post a comment here and I'll see if I can figure it out.